# Whitespace Location Finding

Tags: java, whitespace

So the instructions I have are as follows:

> Write code to print the location of any space in the 2-character string passCode. Each space detected should print a separate statement followed by a newline. Sample output for the given program:
>   Space at 1

The code I currently have written is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindSpaces {
public static void main (String [] args) {
  String passCode = "";
  passCode = "A ";
  if (Character.isWhitespace(passCode.charAt(0))){
     System.out.println("Space at " +passCode.indexOf(" "));
  }
  else if (Character.isWhitespace(passCode.charAt(1))){
     System.out.println("Space at " +passCode.indexOf(" ", 1));
  }
  else{
  }

  return;
    }
  }
```

Now this works sometimes but if I have more than one space in my input, it only ever prints one line. If it helps anyone, it is from zyBooks and I have no idea how to make it bring a second line showing a second whitespace.

Comment: Use two if's not an else if, or a loop with one if. You also don't need the else block or the return statement since `main`'s return type is `void`.

Comment: Also, this would be a bit easier in a `for` loop if you can use one. Then you only need a single `if (Character.isWhitespace(passCode.charAt(i)) { S.o.p("Space at " + i);` If you can use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
if ( condition1 ) {
  doSomething();
}
else if ( condition2 ) {
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

the `else` means that you will only test `condition2` (and so only have a chance of calling `doSomethingElse()`) if `condition1` is false. You just need to remove that `else` from your code.

Answer (score 1):

While the length might be limited to two, I still guess a for loop would fit better:

```
String passCode = "";
passCode = "  ";
for (int i = 0; i < passCode.length(); i++) {
    if (passCode.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        System.out.println("Whitespace at index " + (i + 1));
    }
}
```

To look at your solution: Your code can't enter any output for more than one time. You have if() else() - simply remove the else, and you should be fine:

```
String passCode = "";
passCode = "  ";
if (Character.isWhitespace(passCode.charAt(0))) {
    System.out.println("Space at " + passCode.indexOf(" "));
}
if (Character.isWhitespace(passCode.charAt(1))) {
    System.out.println("Space at " + passCode.indexOf(" ", 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find and print the location of each whitespaces in a string, you simply iterate through the string and check if the current character is a whitespace:

```
String str = "Find the space location";
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
  if(Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) {
     System.out.println("Space at " + i);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Adding some explanation would make this answer more useful.